# SSAS cube having flags and counts in fact table

Tags: ssas, msbi

I am trying to create a cube for bank account opening fact. The fact table will include the below fields.

```
Fact_Clnt_Dtls

BankID

BranchID

PINCode

RMID (relationship manager)

Holder_indicator (1,2,3)

Client_status (1=Active, 2=dormat, 3= closed)

SMS_Flg (Y/N)

SMS_Flg_count

Nomination_Flg (y/n)

Nomination_Flg_count

Auth_sign_flg (Y/N)

Auth_sign_flg_count

Total_Clients (bank id wise count of all clients)

and many more flags



The DIM tables are as below

DIM_Bank_Mstr

BankID

Bank_Name

PINCode

Activation_date



DIM_RM_Mstr

RMID

RM_Name

BankID

PINCode

RM_HOD



DIM_PIN_Code_Mstr

PINCode

Zone

District

State

City
```

DIM_Zero_Bal_acct - (to find out till how long the account was with zero balance and when the account was credited)

```
BankID

ClientID

Activation_Date

First_credit_date
```

Is it a correct design as i have various flags and counts in the fact table. I have created these tables and inserted few sample values but i am not getting the desired result of the cube.

I want to have Bank wise, holder wise, RM wise, all flag wise, region wise etc. count of clients for a period or range of period. I will give access of the cube to the power users and they will use all the dimension in powerpivot to create their own pivot table. I think there is sometime wrong in the table design. Please provide your suggestions.

Regards,

Manish

Comment: Zero Balance Account Is an attribute to the Accounts dimension, just think this way by creating Accounts dimension, some of your flags may move to Accounts dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Put all flags in a junk dimension(s), depending on domain. You might end up with nice, small set of correlated properties - I assume users want to aggregate by those values.

DIM_Zero_Bal_acct seems more like a calculated member candidate than dimension, but I guess it depends on usage and what users expect to see.

Is PIN really in any way connected to Zone/District? If it is build using some Zone ids, then it makes sense, othewise you'll end up with bunch of joins.
Leave non-aggregable things (like... PIN?) in fact table, it can save some space but usually such join is not worth the trouble... and business users probably don't care about aggregating by those values. Unless they are very strange people (like... sociologists).

I'd decide what is transaction in this case first and then build around it - it seems account activation is one of transactions (events in time/other space that can be somehow measurable - counted, in this case). Another transaction is credit. Those are two unrelated fact tables. Sprinkle them with dimensions, extract small flags into junk dimensions (maybe you'll end up with interesting relations between them)... and there you go.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.
I would want to give more clarity on the requirement. We have data related to all the banks in the OLTP system and the management wants to know how many accounts where opened by banks in a zone/city/state in a given period let’s say in the last FY. They want to know the trend of accounts opened by a bank for the past 6 months. How many clients have subscribed for SMS facility (SMS flag = 'Y') or subscribed for reports (Rpt_flg = 'Y') or have opted for nomination etc.

Comment: I will get data from the OLTP system as of yesterday in terms of Bank wise, holder wise and client status wise counts and not the entire client master as there are millions of records.As suggested by you if i put all the flags in a junk dimension table then how would i get the number of client accounts pertaining to these flags for a period. For example how do i get the number of accounts who have subscribed for SMS facility till June 30, 2015. I think i am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have created dimension for Bank, Holder, RM, and then one dimension for each flag field, The approach should work, and one can apply more than one dimension to get the desired result like I can apply bank dimesnion, and SMS flag Dimension to get all the accounts for a selected bank who have applied for SMS facility. I will suggest few changes like

- if a RM is related to a bank, then relate RM to bank dimension instead of creating a separate dimension
- Make Branch code unique(make sure you are not receiving duplicate branch codes if you are receiving data from multiple banks having same branch code internally) in fact table, and combine bank and branch dimensions together, as one branch belongs to the only one bank, so the bank dimension will have BranchID as key.

As long creating junk dimension is concerned you can visit this link http://www.1keydata.com/datawarehousing/junk-dimension.html and see if this helps you, the only concern while using them is if you want to get values from fact by ignoring a flag value completely, I mean you want to get all values immaterial of what a particular flag value is.